# Django filter with inner query?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Based on the following models:

```
class OpportunityDetail(models.Model):
    ContactDetail = models.ForeignKey(ContactDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='OpportunityContactDetails')
    Stage = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique = False, choices=stages)

class ProductDetail(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = False)
    Amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, unique = False)

class ProductItemDetail(models.Model):
    ProductDetail = models.ForeignKey(ProductDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ProductDetails')
    OpportunityDetail = models.ForeignKey(OpportunityDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='OpportunityDetails')
    ChildrenDetail = models.ForeignKey(ChildrenDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ChildrenProduct')
```

When I query the opportunity I would normally do something like this:

```
oppLST = OpportunityDetail.objects.filter(ContactDetail = myCon.id)
```

However, I am wondering how can I get an inner query of the product items? in sql i would do something like:

```
SELECT Id, Stage, (SELECT Id, ProductDetail, ProductDetail.Name FROM ProductItemDetail) FROM OpportunityDetail WHERE ContactDetail = myCon.id
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do something like this in django

Comment: Yes, it's possible to make subqueries within a query with django. To clarify, what do you expect the result of your SQL query to be in the example you give?

Comment: @PeterGalfi in my template I want to loop through opportunities and for eahc one i want to loop through the items, this way i can show a list of opps, and for each opp a list of their items, is it possible to use the query "language of django" ? i mean in the format OpportunityDetail.objects.filter ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to resolve this depending on what are the results you are looking for. Here is one way that may be just sufficient for you. This does not use django subqueries, just collects the details that you need by traversing the foreign key relationhips in your models:

```py
oppLST = OpportunityDetail.objects.filter(ContactDetail=myCon.id).values(
   'id', 'stage', 
   'OpportunityDetails__id', 
   'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__id', 
   'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__Name'
)
```

The above will get you a list of dictionaries, for example:

```
[
  {'id': 1, 'stage': 'Stage 1', 'OpportunityDetails__id': 1, 'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__id': 1, 'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__Name': 'details'},
  {'id': 1, 'stage': 'Stage 1', 'OpportunityDetails__id': 1, 'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__id': 2, 'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__Name': 'details more'},
  {'id': 1, 'stage': 'Stage 1', 'OpportunityDetails__id': 1, 'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__id': 3, 'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__Name': 'details three'},
  {'id': 2, 'stage': 'Stage B', 'OpportunityDetails__id': 2, 'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__id': 5, 'OpportunityDetails__ProductDetail__Name': 'interesting details'},
 ...
]
```

You can take this and then get what you need from it.

As a note you are using "related_name" in your model definitions in a way that is a bit unclear and hides the actual meaning and usage of that attribute. This attribute provides the reverse access through the foreign key and should be named in a way that indicates that. Also to prevent confusion and possible errors, field names in the model should be lower case so you don't mix them up with the actual model name (e.g. `ProductDetail` is a field of ProductItemDetail or is it the model ProductItemDetail model?).

Here's a suggestion:

```py
class OpportunityDetail(models.Model):
    contact_detail = models.ForeignKey(ContactDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='opportunities')
    stage = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique = False, choices=stages)

class ProductDetail(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique = False)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, unique = False)

class ProductItemDetail(models.Model):
    product_detail = models.ForeignKey(ProductDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_items')
    opportunity_detail = models.ForeignKey(OpportunityDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_items')
    children_detail = models.ForeignKey(ChildrenDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_items')
```

With the above corrections the django queryset becomes this:

```
oppLST = OpportunityDetail.objects.filter(contact_detail=myCon.id).values(
   'id', 'stage', 
   'product_items__id', 
   'product_items__product_detail__id', 
   'product_items__product_detail__name'
)
```

Hope this helps, let me know if anything needs clarification.

Addition: you mention in the above comment that you want to use this in a template. You can reference the related name directly in the template as like so:

```py
opportunities = OpportunityDetail.objects.filter(ContactDetail=myCon.id)
```

Template:

```html
{% for opportunity in opportunities %}
     ...
    {% for product_item in opportunity.product_items %}
        <p>{{ product_item.product_detail.id }}</p>
        <p>{{ product_item.product_detail.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is probably the simplest thing that you need. The performance of doing this in the template instead of doing this with a single query before the data hits the template is slightly worse, but would be irrelevant with small datasets.